# How to rewrite the following code in pandas to sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following code written in pandas

```
pd.concat([
        df[['id', 'day','name', 'message', 'answer','status']], 
        df.groupby(['day', 'id'])[['name']].shift(1).add_prefix('next'),
        df.groupby(['day', 'id'])[['message']].shift(1).add_prefix('next'),
        df.groupby(['day', 'id'])[['status']].shift(1).add_prefix('next'),
    ], axis=1)
```

Have no idea which functions can replace add_prefix and shift(1)

So if the dataframe looks like this

```
   id       day        name message answer status
0   1  20210101 15:00  Karan      Hi    Yes     Ok
1   1  20210101 15:10  Rohit     Wow     No     Ok
2   2  20210102 15:00  Sahil     Bye    One     Ko
3   2  20210102 15:10  Aryan    Ciao    Two     Ko
```

The result should look like this

```
   id    daytime       name message answer status nextname nextmessage nextstatus
0   1  20210101 15:00  Karan      Hi    Yes     Ok      Rohit     Wow     Ok
2   2  20210102 15:00  Sahil     Bye    One     Ko      Aryan    Ciao     Ko
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your code and reproduced correctly here

```
import pandas as pd

data={'id':      [1, 1, 2, 2],
      'day':     [20210101, 20210101, 20210102, 20210102],
      'name':    ['Karan', 'Rohit', 'Sahil', 'Aryan'],
      'message': ['Hi', 'Wow', 'Bye', 'Ciao'],
      'answer':  ['Yes', 'No', 'One', 'Two'],
      'status':  ['Ok', 'Ok', 'Ko', 'Ko']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

res = pd.concat([
    df[['id', 'day','name', 'message', 'answer','status']],
    df.groupby(['day', 'id'])[['name']].shift(1).add_prefix('next'),
    df.groupby(['day', 'id'])[['message']].shift(1).add_prefix('next'),
    df.groupby(['day', 'id'])[['status']].shift(1).add_prefix('next'),
], axis=1)

print(res.head(10))
```

all it does is for every `id` and `day` grouping, it takes the previous row and it associates it with the `next` columns... e.g. in my previous example, the original dataset is

```
   id       day   name message answer status
0   1  20210101  Karan      Hi    Yes     Ok
1   1  20210101  Rohit     Wow     No     Ok
2   2  20210102  Sahil     Bye    One     Ko
3   2  20210102  Aryan    Ciao    Two     Ko
```

and the updated is

```
   id       day   name message answer status nextname nextmessage nextstatus
0   1  20210101  Karan      Hi    Yes     Ok      NaN         NaN        NaN
1   1  20210101  Rohit     Wow     No     Ok    Karan          Hi         Ok
2   2  20210102  Sahil     Bye    One     Ko      NaN         NaN        NaN
3   2  20210102  Aryan    Ciao    Two     Ko    Sahil         Bye         Ko
```

If this is the case, then the `add_prefix` can be substituted by naming the column properly and the `next` by the [LAG function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lag-function/)

if you create a PG table and insert the same rows with

```
create table my_test(id int, day int, name varchar, message varchar, answer varchar, status varchar);
insert into my_test values(1, 20210101, 'Karan', 'Hi', 'Yes', 'Ok');
insert into my_test values(1, 20210101, 'Rohit', 'Wow', 'No', 'Ok');
insert into my_test values(2, 20210102, 'Sahil', 'Bye', 'One', 'Ko');
insert into my_test values(2, 20210102, 'Aryan', 'Ciao', 'Two', 'Ko');
```

Then the query is (assuming you order by `ctid` the results, if you have another ordering query substitute it)

```
select id, 
    day, 
    message, 
    answer, 
    status,
    lag(message,1) over (partition by day, id order by ctid) next_message,
    lag(answer,1) over (partition by day, id order by ctid) next_answer,
    lag(status,1) over (partition by day, id order by ctid) next_status
from my_test;
```

With the result being

```
 id |   day    | message | answer | status | next_message | next_answer | next_status 
----+----------+---------+--------+--------+--------------+-------------+-------------
  1 | 20210101 | Hi      | Yes    | Ok     |              |             | 
  1 | 20210101 | Wow     | No     | Ok     | Hi           | Yes         | Ok
  2 | 20210102 | Bye     | One    | Ko     |              |             | 
  2 | 20210102 | Ciao    | Two    | Ko     | Bye          | One         | Ko
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Sorry,that I didn't post the wanted output, I'll edit my post. Thank you a lot! Haven't even heard about lag function